# Narrowed down duplicate, but former question had no answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So here is the first (created earlier) question:
[Styling an icon defined with prepend-icon in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282241/styling-an-icon-defined-with-prepend-icon-in-vuetify)

And second question, which is essentially same as the first one, but dumbed down to a specific use-case, which imo makes it worse, but I guess time (future readers) will tell:

[How to change <v-text-field> icon's color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270498/how-to-change-v-text-field-icons-color)

But the second question received an answer *before* the first question, so it was not possible to flag it as a duplicate.
I posted an answer to a first question because I believe it's better (both question and the answer actually), and might gain more traction.

Should I flag any as a duplicate? Or perhaps just leave a comment somewhere to link one with another? Or create a new answer on the second question?

My thought was to let the answerer of the second question that it's promoting a [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) and potential side effects, and then mark that question as a duplicate of the first one.

Comment: Note, you need an upvote or acceptance for the first Q&A to be a valid duplicate target. If/when that's done, I suggest voting to close the second as a duplicate of the more general first. You'll need some others in the community to agree with your vote before it happens.

Comment: @jpp Oh, thanks for the heads-up, I didn't realize that. And thanks for the suggestion.